# Is there a good RAM health scanner available?

Tags: memory, mysql

I have an [issue that I'm trying to figure out](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50216&thanks=3&notify=211) with MySQL Workbench 5.2.34 on Win7 64-bit Ultimate. The exception information says

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

I would like to make sure my memory is okay just in case.  I've googled for some, but the top results looked a little dodgy to me.  Any Ideas?

Comment: "corrupt" here means "corrupt" in a logical sense, not necessarily physical. If the error occurs more than once with MySQL Workbench, but not in other programs, it is certainly a bug in MySQL Workbench and not a physical problem with your RAM.

Answer (score 8):

[Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) is usually said to be the best memory testing tool.  It's free, open source, and you can boot it off of a USB key (or CD if you like).  You should also test any new RAM you place in your system (even if it's brand new).

Memtest86+ is also available on the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 installers have a memory diagnostic tool, or you can get microsoft's memory diagnostic tool [here](http://oca.microsoft.com/en/windiag.asp). I'd generally trust memtest, but if for whatever reason it didn't work, or find anything, it might be a alternative you could try.